# What is umask command for?

Tags: utilities

What actually is `umask` command for in *nix OS?
How is its working mechanism and usefulness ?
e.g

```
$ umask 022
```

Thanks much before

Comment: Have you read the man page of this utility?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Note that just typing `man umask` in the terminal will not give them the manual for the `umask` command, since it's a built-in command.  They will want to read the manual of their shell.

Answer (score 5):

`umask` is a builtin command of most shells which is just an interface to the `umask()` system call, and you'll find its description in the documentation of your shell (beware `man umask` may point you to the documentation of the `umask()` system call instead or of the `umask` builtin of a shell other than yours).

The user mask is an attribute of a process (inherited from parent to children and preserved upon command execution) that determines what permissions are automatically given to files by default when created.

The `umask` utility allows you to set the user mask of the shell process to control the permissions of the files created by any commands run within the shell session.

The `umask` of all shells take the mask as an octal number, while on some shells, including all POSIX ones, it can also be specified in a symbolic form like for `chmod`.

The mask determines which bits of the permissions should be *cleared* when the file is created. For instance `umask 777`, where 0777 is 511 or 0b111_111_111 would cause files to be created with no permission as all 9¹ bits of the Unix file permissions (3 (`r`read, `w`rite, e`x`excute) for *user*, 3 for *group*, 3 for *other*) would be cleared.

The symbolic form specifies which bits should *not* be cleared. So `umask 777` would be `umask u=,g=,o=`.

Generally, you want at least the umask to include the `w` bit for `o`thers as you don't want the files you create to be world writable (`umask 002` or `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`).

You'll likely want the `w` bit for `g`roup to be set as well at least on systems where the primary group of the user is not a personal one (is shared with other users): `umask 022` or `umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`.

A `umask 077` or `umask u=rwx,g=,o=` ensures that all files you create are private to you (not accessible by anyone else). You often see that in scripts that create temporary files, sometimes in a subshell as in:

```
(umask 077; echo test > "$tmpfile")
```

Setting `umask` bits for the `u`ser can cause problems, as you can end up creating files that not even you can open.

Note that the user mask applied *on top* of the permissions requested by applications when they `open()` or `creat()` a file. If they do `creat("file", 0666)` while `umask` is `022` (`u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`), the permissions will end up being `0644` (`u=rw,g=r,o=r`).  Applications can still call `fchmod()` or `chmod()` afterwards to change the permissions as they like (and the umask has no effect there).

`umask` without arguments reports the current user mask in octal form. `umask -S` in some shells report it in symbolic form. `umask -p` in `bash` or `fish` outputs shell code which once interpreted would set the same user mask.

That can be used to restore the previous umask after you have modified it:

```
previous_umask=$(umask)
umask 077
# create some private files
umask "$previous_umask"
```

---

<sup>¹ Technically, there are 12 bits of permissions where the 3 extra ones are special bits used for various purposes depending on the type of the file and sometimes combined with other permission bits (like the setuid, setgid bits for executables, `t` bit for directories...). On some systems those bits are ignored when requested in `open()`/`creat()` and anyway when they're set by applications (generally rather via `chmod()` afterwards), it's for a good reason, so it's not generally useful to include them in the `umask` and the `umask()` system call will ignore them anyway.</sup>